# 'Seed' is not defined no-undef. seed.js has IIFE

Tags: reactjs, iife

In React Fullstack by Accomazzo book, in the first chapter they used seed.js as a data source. it has IIFE and they used window object to use it anywhere in the project. but when i created my own react project and followed along the codes it shows an error saying Seed is not defined no-undef

I have tried importing, including the js file in html file but those didn't seem to work

this is the app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
class PlayerList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const player = Seed.players[0]
    return (
      <div className='ui unstackable items'>
        <Player 
        id={player.id}
        name={player.name}
        club={player.club}
        url={player.url}
        votes={player.votes}
        submitterAvatarUrl={player.submitterAvatarUrl}
        playerImgUrl={player.playerImgUrl}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is the seed.js file

```
window.Seed = (function () {
  function generateVoteCount() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 15);
  }

  const players = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'CR7',
      club: 'Juventus',
      url: '#',
      votes: generateVoteCount(),
      submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/profile-pic.jpeg',
      playerImgUrl: 'images/players/CR7.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'LM10',
      club: 'Barcelona',
      url: '#',
      votes: generateVoteCount(),
      submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/kristy.png',
      playerImgUrl: 'images/players/LM10.jp',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'MS10',
      club: 'Liverpool',
      url: '#',
      votes: generateVoteCount(),
      submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/veronika.jpg',
      playerImgUrl: 'images/players/MS10.jpg',
    },
  ];

  return { players: players };
}());
```

Comment: have you tried `const player = window.Seed.players[0]`? Also you need to make sure seed.js is the first JS file you include in your bundle/html.

Comment: Have you checked if in the browser Seed is available? are you sure seed.js is being loaded?

Comment: `window.Seed.players[0]` worked for me, thanks, @Clarity. Also, how do i check if in browser Seed is available, @F.bernal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a working example, just import your seed file. Basically, you only need to `import 'seed'` and to avoid errors add `window.Seed`

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-import-iife-5mojf

Comment: that worked for me, thanks! but for some reason the images don't show up now. as you can see i included them in the seed.js file with the correct pathing but i wonder why they are not showing up?

Comment: If it resolves you must mark it as resolved, the error of the image is another issue and you must show more information about it.

Comment: i marked it as resolved. The pathing in src file are as below: inside **src** file there are _app.js, seed.js, images (images file also has 2 subfolders called players and avatars), app.css, index.js, app.test.js_ and the pathing for in **public** file are:  _index.html_. what other information should i give?